# apache commons configuration: setting an xml namespace for the root element

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

When saving a configuration file, I need to specify the xmlns for the root element (by default `<configuration>`). The reason is, I validate (with a schema) upon loading the configuration file later.

I can't seem to find how commons-configuration exposes this functionalities. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There is a [`setRootNode(ConfigurationNode rootNode)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/HierarchicalConfiguration.html#setRootNode(org.apache.commons.configuration.tree.ConfigurationNode)) that might work. You can set an attribute (xmlns in this case) on the [`ConfigurationNode`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/tree/ConfigurationNode.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`setRootNode(ConfigurationNode rootNode)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/HierarchicalConfiguration.html#setRootNode%28org.apache.commons.configuration.tree.ConfigurationNode%29) that might work. You can set an attribute (xmlns in this case) on the [`ConfigurationNode`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/tree/ConfigurationNode.html).

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion by @maba works. It's not pretty, but there doesn't seem to be a more elegant way to do this. Here's the code:

```
private void setNameSpace(XMLConfiguration conf) {
    HierarchicalConfiguration.Node root = new HierarchicalConfiguration.Node(
            "configuration");
    root.addAttribute(new HierarchicalConfiguration.Node("xmlns",
            "http://namespace.com"));
    conf.setRootNode(root);
}
```

Where the relevant imports are:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.HierarchicalConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration;
```